# What are the downsides of developing your React-Native project with expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have recently built a whole React Native project using expo. I have no prior experience with neither Xcode/Swift or Android Studio. I was wondering if you could share some of your experiences of the disadvantages with using expo instead of plain React Native?

Comment: The biggest thing is that you can't use external native libraries, you can use only the native libraries included with expo. The bundle size of your app tends to be a lot larger as well.

Comment: @MattAft unless you ejected your project ofc. But in general expo have a step ahead comparing to bare RN projects in terms of some ready very useful native libraries (BarcodeScanner, MapView, ImagePicker) and others. For me I prefer a bare RN project and expo still very useful in some specific cases since it helps building features very quick.

Comment: @Mostav yeah but if you eject, then you're not really using expo anymore ;) you can also import any of those expo libraries into bare RN apps as well. but yeah in general expo makes a lot of things easier, just need to balance the benefits/drawbacks and decide what's best for the project

Answer (score 0):

I used Expo mainly in 2018 and the experience of using Expo is generally positive. There can be bugs in the Expo libraries and the documentation isn't complete. The short update cycles mattered for me since they include bug fixes and features.

There are some libraries that I wish I can use but detaching from Expo seemed too daunting. Expect that you'll generally stick with features provided by Expo unless you absolutely need a feature.